# Calling webview method from JNI

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-webview

I subclassed WebView and added a native methods in that call which is implemented as:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_mypackage_openUrl(
        JNIEnv* env, jobject webView, jstring url) {
    LOGI("openUrl");

    jclass webViewClass = env->GetObjectClass(webView);
    if (!webViewClass) {
        LOGE("webView class not found");
        return false;
    }

    jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(webViewClass, "loadUrl",
            "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    env->CallObjectMethod(webViewClass, method, url);

}
```

But it does not work and application would crash, I know that WebView method must be called from UI(main) thread, but still I need to understand if this possible from JNI side?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use CallBack mechanism to send command+data from c/c++ to java class.
Many tutorials exist, you could also search on stackoverflow.

For instance:
[How to create callbacks between android code and native code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377168/how-to-create-callbacks-between-android-code-and-native-code#13397357)

Comment: @LarentY if i callback then it will be a compromise with security of my data.

Comment: @AbhishekK all is in your android app WebView, JNI, Java classes, c/c++. so if it's just for "hide" data that transfered to WebView, if your app is corrupted, your webview is corrupted.